# insert new rows to the time series data, with date added automatically

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a time-series data frame looks like:

```
            TS.1
2015-09-01 361656.7
2015-09-02 370086.4
2015-09-03 346571.2
2015-09-04 316616.9
2015-09-05 342271.8
2015-09-06 361548.2
2015-09-07 342609.2
2015-09-08 281868.8
2015-09-09 297011.1
2015-09-10 295160.5
2015-09-11 287926.9
2015-09-12 323365.8
```

Now, what I want to do is add some new data points (rows) to the existing data frame, say,

```
320123.5
323521.7
```

How can I added corresponding date to each row? The data is just sequentially inhered from the last row.

Is there any package can do this automatically, so that the only thing I do is to insert new data point?

Comment: You just want to append the new observations to the bottom of the table, in the order you already have them?

Comment: that is the normal way. I want to know, is there more efficient way to do this, which automatically add date information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some play data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-31"), "days"), x = seq(31)) 
new.x <- c(32, 33)
```

This adds the extra observations along with the proper sequence of dates:

```
new.df <- data.frame(date=seq(max(df$date) + 1, max(df$date) + length(new.x), "days"), x=new.x)
```

Then just `rbind` them to get your expanded data frame:

```
rbind(df, new.df)

         date  x
1  2015-01-01  1
2  2015-01-02  2
3  2015-01-03  3
4  2015-01-04  4
5  2015-01-05  5
6  2015-01-06  6
7  2015-01-07  7
8  2015-01-08  8
9  2015-01-09  9
10 2015-01-10 10
11 2015-01-11 11
12 2015-01-12 12
13 2015-01-13 13
14 2015-01-14 14
15 2015-01-15 15
16 2015-01-16 16
17 2015-01-17 17
18 2015-01-18 18
19 2015-01-19 19
20 2015-01-20 20
21 2015-01-21 21
22 2015-01-22 22
23 2015-01-23 23
24 2015-01-24 24
25 2015-01-25 25
26 2015-01-26 26
27 2015-01-27 27
28 2015-01-28 28
29 2015-01-29 29
30 2015-01-30 30
31 2015-01-31 31
32 2015-02-01 32
33 2015-02-02 33
```